# how to navigate to subdirectories in a shell script

Tags: shell

I am having a directory.This directory has a lot of subdirectories which contain html pages and some c source code files,Makefiles etc etc.The script I am trying to write would be executed from one directory which has all these subdirectories.
Following is the set of directories and files you can see

```
ls
delete.sh  lddbus   Makefile      misc-progs  sbull  scullc  scullp  short       simple  snull  usb
include    LICENSE  misc-modules  pci         scull  sculld  scullv  shortprint  skull   tty
```

Some of them are directories and some are files in the subdirectories above there are further subdirectories and html pages also which I want to eliminate.
The manual way would be do go to each directory and remove the pages via following command

```
rm *.html*
```

Since the html page has name ending with `?=/something`  sort of names.
So I decided to write a shell script.
But what I am not clear is how will I take directory names as arguments in my shell script.If I decided to use a for loop or some thing similar.
In this case what should I be doing?
I do not want to use

```
find . -name '*.html*' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

As I am doing this for learning purpose.

Comment: Easiest way: use a recursive function.

Comment: I am not clear with this can you give some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet will run `ls` for every subdirectory in current dir:

```
for d in * .[!.]* ..?*; do
    test -d "${d}" && ls "${d}"
done
```

You can adapt it to run a command, for each subdirectory, that you like.

If you want to get deeper in the directory hierarchy, you can wrap this code in a function and rerun it for every subdir.

```
function f {
    cd "$1"
    # do something in this dir
    for d in * .[!.]* ..?*; do
        cd "$1"
        test -d "$1/$d" && f "$1/$d"
    done
}

f "`pwd`"
```

For Zsh you'd probably want to set NULL_GLOB option (-G switch), so it doesn't report errors if there are no hidden dirs, in Bash it works by default.

Comment: Wow this great.I never came across any such thing.
I was thinking of some thing very very big logic.
 How do you write this command in for `ls -1` where did you learn this?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to parse the output of `ls`. Read [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to find out why.

Comment: It is for learning purpose I am not concerned right now to parse the output of ls but any how thanks for this information I will have a look at it.

Comment: @Bond: It's never too soon to learn good programming practices

Comment: @SiegeX: not a real concern for normal use cases, especially if you run this in a directory tree that you know doesn't have any weird characters in file names.

Comment: @maarons: That may be the case now, but how easy it would be for that to change down the road or for somebody to use your code on a system where you cannot assume as such.  Considering the effort to do this in a way that doesn't fall to pitfalls that `ls` does is just as easy, if not easier, I don't see a good reason to practice bad habits.

Comment: SiegeX: With GNU Make having huge problems with spaces in file names, problems with `ls` and control characters seem almost non-existent=)  But in general, yeah if you're really going for "and what if?" approach `ls` isn't the best solution.

Comment: Replace the `\`ls -1\`` with a `*` to get correct behavior in the corner cases.

Comment: @Dennis: No, it couldn't, because this script relies on absolute paths to get back into the top directory inside for loop.

Comment: @maarons: Relying on absolute paths is fragile: if a directory is renamed while your script executes, you're in trouble. (`find` has the same problem to a lesser extent.) It's easy to avoid here: perform each descent in a subshell, i.e. put the code of the function in parentheses.

Comment: Note that `*` does not match subdirectories whose name begins with a dot. You can use `* .[!.]* ..*` instead.

Comment: @Giles - aren't we being a little paranoid, considering what happens when directory is renamed?  Many things will fail then, spawning a new process for every directory seems extreme, not to mention potentially killing if there are lots of directories.

Comment: @Gilles: as for the dotfiles ..* would match .. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @maarons: Oops, the last pattern should have been `..?*`.

Answer (score 3):

With bash 4 (or zsh) you can use globstar "**" to match recursively.

```
shopt -s globstar
echo **/*html*
```

With a directory setup like this:

```
mkdir -p {a..b}/{c..d}
touch {a..b}/{c..d}/{e..f}.{htmlx,other}
```

It will result in:

```
a/c/e.htmlx a/c/f.htmlx a/d/e.htmlx a/d/f.htmlx b/c/e.htmlx b/c/f.htmlx b/d/e.htmlx b/d/f.htmlx
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` is the way to go. You will not learn anything useful choosing the wrong way to solve a problem.

Print a list of files you want to remove

```
find /your/dir -type f -iname '*.html*'
```

and delete them

```
find /your/dir -type f -iname '*.html*' -delete
```

`find` is a powerful command, learn to use it.

Another way to improve the command you don't want to use:

```
find /your/dir -type f -name '*.html*' -exec rm -f {} +
```

(hint: `man find` to learn how `-exec ;` and `-exec +` differ)

Note that shell scripting is just using in the best useful way the small programs like `find`, `cat`, `ls`, `wc`, etc. Knowing these utilities thoroughly is a necessary requisite to learn shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like so:

```
myfunc()
{
  for dir; do
      if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
          echo rm -rf "${dir}/*.html*"
      else
          echo "No such dir '$dir'"
      fi
  done
}
```

Then call the function by passing the directories you want to remove *.html* from

#### Output

```
$ myfunc /foo /etc /root
No such dir '/foo'
rm -rf /etc/*.html*
rm -rf /root/*.html*
```

Once you are satisfied with the output, remove the `echo` to have it really delete the files.

Comment: and how do I test if the given thing is a directory?

Comment: Updated to check each arg for directory status

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [maarons' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264529/how-to-navigate-to-subdirectories-in-a-shell-script/4264551#4264551), but with two advantages:

- Using `*/` instead of `*` in the `for` loop means it only iterates over directories instead of all files for a potentially big speedup
- Using `pushd` and `popd` makes it easy to support `.` or no argument to mean the current directory.

Here is the function:

```
g () {
    local d bb=/dev/null # bit-bucket
    pushd "$1" > $bb
    pwd    # do something (pwd is a placeholder)
    for d in */
    do
        test -d "$PWD/$d" && g "$PWD/$d"    # you could use $(pwd) instead of $PWD
    done
    popd > $bb
}
```

Of course, using `find` with `-execdir` is simpler and gives the same results.:

```
find -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir sh -c 'cd {}; pwd' \;    # (pwd` is a placeholder)
```

Comment: @Gilles: That's true for the function I posted. The `find` version doesn't (unless you add `-L`).

Comment: With `*/` rather than `*`, the function will recurse into symbolic links to directories.