# Shell script to execute over 1000 binaries in subdirectories

Tags: shell, subdirectory, binaries

I am running a certain test utility called - Open Posix testsuite, which comprises of over 1000 tests. There is a script included in the suite to run these tests which I cannot use on my target machine.

I can however run a shell script, but having never written a serious shell script - I need some help here.

My script requirements: I need to execute all these 1000+ tests from these subdirectories. The structuring is somewhat like this. The main directory (where the script will reside) has 3 sub-directories. Each of these sub-directories has 2-10 sub-directories and it keeps getting deeper. At the end, most of these directories will have at least 2, and perhaps at most 40 ".test" files (per subdirectory) which are the binaries I need to execute. To be on the safe side, I'd need to do a chmod 777 on the ".test" files before execution.

This answer perhaps will provide some help - [how to navigate to subdirectories in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264529/how-to-navigate-to-subdirectories-in-a-shell-script)

Thanks a lot! Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```sh
#!/bin/sh

find -type f | while read
do
  chmod 777 "$REPLY"
  "$REPLY"
done
```